# OSD notification for Irssi

Tags: perl, notifications, irc, irssi

I want to get a notification each time I get a /query message or get highlighted in a channel.
this notification should be in the form of bubble OSD (on screen Display).

If OSD isn't possible for Linux, I'll settle for bringing the terminal window containing the `irssi` instance to the top of the window stack and flickering window's name in status bar.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Patrick Notification on screen for IrssI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy enough to set up using the [fnotify script](https://github.com/rndstr/fnotify/blob/master/fnotify.pl). Set it to [autoload](http://scripts.irssi.org/) and then customise it to print to a file of your choosing:

```
sub filewrite {
    my ($text) = @_;
    # FIXME: there is probably a better way to get the irssi-dir...
        open(FILE,">>$ENV{HOME}/path/to/your/fnotified");
    print FILE $text . "\n";
        close (FILE);
}
```

Then, use [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to watch that directory or file, and trigger a message when new lines are written to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# script to push IRC highlight notifications

dir="$HOME/path/to/your/"

while inotifywait -qqre attrib "$dir" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    echo "IRC:" "You have been pinged..." |  notify-send IRC "You have been pinged…" \
    -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/status/dialog-warning.png
done
```

I run `irssi` on a headless server, so I sync the watched directory to all of the other machines I use with [Pulse, (formerly Syncthing)](https://ind.ie/pulse/), and then run the `inotify` script on those local machines so that, wherever I am logged on, I will get notified if I am pinged...

You can run the `inotify` script from a service file if you use `systemd` or however you would like to start it on login.

If you don't want to use `notify-send`, [dzen](https://github.com/robm/dzen) is an excellent choice for an unobtrusive notification application.

Comment: it is great but is there a way to say from which channel at least. 15 character is another way to identify the ping.

Comment: @r004 You could parse the highlights file for the channel: `awk 'END{print $1}' highlight_file`...